# Translating State Names in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, mapping

I have a list of cities and states in a CSV: row[0] is cities, row[1] is full state names.  I want row[2] (currently empty) to be state abbreviations.

I also have a list like this:

```
name_to_abbr: {"VERMONT": "VT", "GEORGIA": "GA", "IOWA": "IA",
...
}
```

How do I use this?
EG (Pseudocode)

```
If row[1].upper() == (one of the first items in pair sets):
     row[2] = (the corresponding second item in pair)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name_to_abbr` is a dictionary, not a list. You have several options for accessing its contents:

Use `try`:

```
try:
    row[2] = name_to_abbr[row[1].upper()]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
row[2] = name_to_abbr.get(row[1].upper(), "")
```

Or check for keys with `in`:

```
s = row[1].upper()
if s in name_to_abbr:
    row[2] = name_to_abbr[s]
```